# Output Audio from a pc to an iphone bluetooth

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I appear to be having issues with my headphones port in my laptop, when plugging in my headphones they do not appear in the sound devices settings. I have attempted to follow some other suggestions including downloading a IDT HD Audio driver which did not work, downloaded airfoil which worked via WIFI however would prefer to use bluebooth to prevent audio delay. Looking to cut some videos on a long trip overseas and want to be able to use my headphones so that I do not disturb anyone. Any suggestions or recommendations until I buy a new laptop?

Comment: If it helps, you can buy a small Bluetooth audio receiver for $10-15, or a USB audio interface to plug in your headphones.

Comment: After thinking about the question I have just realised I can buy some bluetooth headphones for $20 @ kmart  -

Comment: Ok! Leave the question open, though, as any answers might help someone in the future. :)